# Find the arc length of a cardioid

Tags: calculus, functions

Can anyone help me find the length of a cardioid parameterized as follows:
$$\rho(\theta)=\frac{p}{1+\cos\theta},\quad |\theta|\leq \pi/2$$
I tried the ordinary way but can't get the right answer which must be $p(\sqrt 2 + \ln(1+\sqrt 2)$.

Comment: What is the "ordinary way"?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: pluton, well I tried finding the derivative and then by the formula for length of a cardioid, still get a wrong answer.

Comment: Please detail what you have achieved in your question and use Latex commands. Thanks

Comment: You mean [that kind](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408s/m408d/CurrentWeb/LM10-4-4.php) of ordinary way?

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%3D1%2F(1%2Bcos(theta)),+theta+from+-pi%2F2+to+pi%2F2) gives both explicit and numeric results.

Comment: Seeing the tangents in Alpha's answer makes me guess it used the $z=\tan \frac \theta 2$ substitution.

Comment: Honestly, I agree with the previous comments. You should give an idea of what you've tried. 
However, the cardioid is defined as $\rho(\theta)=p(1+cos(\theta))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you provide is not a cardioid but a parabola ! (The equation of the cardioid would be $\rho=1+\cos\theta$.)

WLOG, $p=1$.

For convenience, we convert to Cartesian coordinates.

$$\rho+\rho\cos\theta=1,$$

$$\rho=1-x,$$

$$x^2+y^2=(1-x)^2,$$

$$x=\frac{1-y^2}2.$$

The extreme points are $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$.

The length is given by

$$S=\int_{y=-1}^1\sqrt{1+y^2}\,dy.$$

By parts,

$$S=\left.y\sqrt{1+y^2}\right|_{-1}^1-\int_{y=-1}^1\frac{1+y^2-1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\,dy,
\\=2\sqrt2-S+\int_{y=-1}^1\frac1{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\,dy.$$

Then

$$S=\sqrt2+\text{arsinh}(1)=\sqrt2+\log(1+\sqrt2).$$